# "ssh-keygen -R ipaddress" blocks when executed with Ansible

Tags: windows, ssh, ansible

When I tried to add my host's hostkey to a windows machine, I experienced a weird behavior. The following task blocks on the first line

```
- name: Add controller to vm's known_hosts
  ansible.windows.win_shell: |
    ssh-keygen -R {{ hostvars.localhost.vmgwv4.stdout }} 
    ssh-keyscan {{ hostvars.localhost.vmgwv4.stdout }} | Add-Content -Path $env:UserProfile/.ssh/known_hosts
```

If I manually connect to the Windows VM with SSH (which is the transport used in the playbook), that command works fine. But when used as above in ansible, `ssh-keygen -R` generates instead a *new* `known_hosts` file `known_hosts.qP3nC66uaB` and blocks the Ansible process. I don't know what it's waiting for.

Does somebody have any explanation for this? If I comment out the first line, it works and the host is added, though multiple times. That was the purpose of the first command, which first erases all keys for the host's IP address (VM's Gateway).

(Note that I can't use "ansible.builtin.known_hosts" because it's Posix-Only. And even If I could, I would be interested in knowing why the above blocks).